# Why is margin-top going in the opposite way and margin-bottom isn't moving at all?

Tags: html, css

As the title mentions, this problem is quite specific and I can't seem to find an answer for it anywhere. I'm trying to add the text "2017 Indie" to the very bottom of the page. When I do margin-top to some pixel value, the text will remain the same and nothing changes, but when I do margin-bottom it creates extra white space above the division I'm in which is the opposite of what I want. I'm not sure what the problem is.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}

* {
  margin: 0;
}

.sect1 h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sect1-1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.sect1-text {
  text-align: center;
}

.sect1 p {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 250px;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text3-1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: block;
}

.text3-1 p {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#p1 {
  top: 540px;
  padding-left: 520px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 42px;
}

#p2 {
  top: 840px;
  padding-left: 220px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#p3 {
  color: black;
  top: 2935px;
  padding-left: 665px;
}

iframe {
  position: absolute;
}

.sect {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.subSect {
  height: 51.75%;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0;
}

.sect1 {
  background-image: url("images/image4.jpg");
}

.sect2 {
  background-image: url("images/image5.jpg");
}

.sect3 {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("images/image2.jpg");
}

script {
  padding-left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sect sect1">
  <div class="sect1-1">
    <h1>Indie</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="sect1-text">
    <p>What music</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="subSect">
  <div class="text">
    <p>This is about....</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="sect sect2">
</div>

<div class="subSect"></div>


<div class="sect3">
  <div class="text3-1">
    <p>2017 Indie</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code doesn't run as one would expect. Please review your code and reproduce the error in debuggable code

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view the `margin` works as expected. The problem is the containing `div`. 
You set `sect3` to a `height` of 100%. Using this style causes the div to appear with the height of the parent element wich is the body tag. Removing the height style will fix the problem if i understood the problem right.

If it is necessary to keep the height of 100% you must add some additional styling to position the text right at the end.

Add `position: relative` to the container `sect3`
then position the `text3-1` div at the bottom e.g.

```
.text3-1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}

* {
  margin: 0;
}

.sect1 h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sect1-1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.sect1-text {
  text-align: center;
}

.sect1 p {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 250px;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text3-1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: block;
}

.text3-1 p {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#p1 {
  top: 540px;
  padding-left: 520px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 42px;
}

#p2 {
  top: 840px;
  padding-left: 220px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#p3 {
  color: black;
  top: 2935px;
  padding-left: 665px;
}

iframe {
  position: absolute;
}

.sect {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.subSect {
  height: 51.75%;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0;
}

.sect1 {
  background-image: url("images/image4.jpg");
}

.sect2 {
  background-image: url("images/image5.jpg");
}

.sect3 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("images/image2.jpg");
}

script {
  padding-left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sect sect1">
  <div class="sect1-1">
    <h1>Indie</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="sect1-text">
    <p>What music</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="subSect">
  <div class="text">
    <p>This is about....</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="sect sect2">
</div>

<div class="subSect"></div>


<div class="sect3">
  <div class="text3-1">
    <p>2017 Indie</p>
  </div>
</div>
```